# Is changing the columns of a matrix a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For example suppose I have a transformation that subtracts the first column of a matrix from every other column. This seems like a linear transformation to me but I'm having trouble coming up with the corresponding matrix. 
I don't think this is the case for transformations on rows however.

Comment: What happens if you do this transformation on the identity matrix?

Answer (score 1):

The mapping

$$L: \mathbb R^{n\times n}\to\mathbb R^{n\times n}$$

defined as

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \dots & a_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \dots & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}-a_{11} & \dots & a_{1n}-a_{11}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}-a_{21} & \dots & a_{2n}-a_{21}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & a_{n2}-a_{n1} & \dots & a_{nn}-a_{n1}
\end{bmatrix}$$

is a linear transformation. You can easily show this to be true by proving that it satisfies all the conditions that a linear transformation needs to satisfy:

1. If $A, B\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, then $L(A+B)=L(A)+L(B)$
2. If $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, then $L(\lambda A)=\lambda\cdot L(A)$

---

However, it is a transformation mapping from a $n^2$ dimensional space onto a $n^2$ dimensional  space, so the matrix for it would need to have $n^2$ columns and $n^2$ rows (the exact shape of the matrix depends, as always, on your choice of basis).

Answer (score 0):

Let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix whose indexes are given by $\delta_{ij}$ (that is to say $1$ for the entry at row $i$ and column $j$, and $0$ everywhere else).

A simple computation shows that $AE_{ij}$ is the matrix whose $j$-th column is the $i$-th column of $A$, and $0$'s on all the other columns.

So "a transformation that subtracts the first column of a matrix from every other column" is given by the map $A \mapsto A-\sum_{j=2}^nAE_{1j}=A(I-\sum_{j=2}^nE_{1j})$.

Note that $(I-\sum_{j=2}^nE_{1j})$ is invertible.